# Is there any way to define a model's attribute as always html_safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, xss

I have a model called `Feature` with a variable called `body_string`, which contains HTML markup I'd like to render, rather than escape.

Every time I reference `body_string` in my views, I need to use `<%=raw` or `.html_safe`.  This seems redundant and not-so-DRY.

Is there any way that I can establish once-and-for-all the `body_string` variable as `html_safe`?

I'm assuming this would happen in the `app/models/feature.rb` file, but I can't figure out what the right syntax would be, exactly.  I've thought of this:

```
def body_string
  return self.body_string.html_safe
end
```

But Rails doesn't like it; it raises a `stack level too deep` exception.

Naturally I could define a variable/method with a different name:

```
def safe_body_string
  return self.body_string.html_safe
end
```

And then just change all references in the views from `body_string` to `safe_body_string`.  But somehow this seems almost as un-DRY as simply using `raw` or `.html_safe` in the first place.

Any insights to how best to handle this?  I feel like there must be something really elegant that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: You should probably be using `raw` every time you want to output `body_string`, regardless of DRY (it's only 3 characters). There is a reason you are forced to be very explicit when you intend to output unencoded HTML, and developers expect to *see* you being explicit. You're effectively moving display logic into the model and you're making it a lot less obvious for people looking at your views that raw HTML is being sent to the browser.

Comment: I regret that I have only one upvote to give to @meagar's comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use [`read_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/read_attribute) to avoid the recursive call to `body_string`:

```
def body_string
  read_attribute(:body_string).html_safe
end
```

`read_attribute` is complemented by [`write_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/write_attribute) for setting attributes from within your model.

A note on style: Don't use explicit `return`s unless you actually need them. The result of the last statement in a method is implicitly the value returned from the method.

Comment: I would change to read_attribute(:body_string).try(:html_safe), so it doesn't throw errors when the attribute is nil

Answer (score 1):

While @meager's answer will definitely work, I don't think this logic belongs in a model. Simply because it adds view-level concerns (HTML safeness) to the model layer, which should just include business logic. Instead, I would recommend using a Presenter for this (see http://nithinbekal.com/posts/rails-presenters/ or find a gem for this -- I personally love [Display Case](https://github.com/objects-on-rails/display-case)). Your presenter can easily override the `body_string` method and provide the `.html_safe` designation when displaying in the view. This way you separate your concerns and can continue to get `body_string` from other models without mixing in the view concern.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this gem is useful for you. I also wanted to stop repeating html_safe all the time when the content is completely trustable.

http://rubygems.org/gems/html_safe_attribute

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use this approach,

```
def body_string
  super && super.html_safe
end
```